# How to optimize the product fetching query

Tags: mysql

I have used below query for product listing. Query is working fine but it takes approximately 0.4534 seconds. How can I optimize the same query.

`SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS DISTINCT tp.prod_id, tp.prod_name, tp.prod_shop, tp.prod_retail_price, tp.prod_sale_price, tp.prod_initial_price, tp.prod_stock, ts.shop_id, ts.shop_name, ts.shop_logo, ts.shop_description, ts.shop_title, tu.user_profile_image, ( SELECT pdiscount_price FROM tbl_product_discounts tpd WHERE tpd.pdiscount_product_id = tp.prod_id AND tpd.pdiscount_qty = '1' AND( ( tpd.pdiscount_start_date = '0000-00-00' OR tpd.pdiscount_start_date < NOW()) AND( tpd.pdiscount_end_date = '0000-00-00' OR tpd.pdiscount_end_date > NOW()) ) ORDER BY tpd.pdiscount_priority ASC, tpd.pdiscount_price ASC LIMIT 1 ) AS discount FROM  tbl_products tp LEFT JOIN  tbl_shops ts ON tp.prod_shop = ts.shop_id AND ts.shop_is_deleted = 0 INNER JOIN  tbl_users tu ON ts.shop_user_id = tu.user_id WHERE tp.prod_is_deleted = '0' LIMIT 0, 20`

Comment: No way to comment without knowing the volume of rows and indexing plan.

Comment: I would be tempted to rewrite the correlated subquery as an uncorrelated one. Also note that LIMIT without ORDER BY is fairly meaningless

Answer (score 0):

Without checking you table or Requirement :

1. Try to use `group by` instead of `DISTINCT`
2. Do not use `sub query`  if possible .
3. Try To use indexing in you table .

This will help you to optimize you query.

Comment: In MySQL, `DISTINCT` is often implemented using `GROUP BY`, so I'm not sure how helpful your first suggestion would be.

Comment: https://www.sitepoint.com/community/t/mysql-when-group-by-is-faster-than-distinct/272420